# Filter Process by Starttime PowerShell

Tags: .net, c, powershell

I have an application which should filter a `Process` by Processname (this is working fine) and starttime.

But I can't filter by startfine.

I'm trying with the code below. Can anyone help me?

```
#Process DropDown Choose 
    $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
    #Write-Host $Choice
    $MyChoice = $Choice
    #Write-Host $MyChoice
    $Script:Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()

#Date DropDown Choose
    $DtChoice = $DtDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()

    #Write-Host $Choice
    $MyDtChoice = $DtChoice
    #Write-Host $MyChoice
    $Script:DtChoice = $DtDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()

#Fill Datagrid

$gps = Get-Process |  Where-Object {($_.ProcessName -like "$choice" ) -and ($_.ProcessName -like "$Dtchoice" ) } |Select-Object id,name,cpu,starttime  |Sort-Object -Descending starttime  
$list = New-Object System.collections.ArrayList
$list.AddRange($gps)`
```

`$DtDropDown` works like this:

```
#region Seleção de Data
[array ]$DtConsulta   = @(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

$DtDropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DtDropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,80)
$DtDropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(240,30)
$DtDropDown.DropDownStyle = "DropDownList" # This style of combobox will prevent blank
# item selection.

#Preenchimento da lista de seleção de datas permitidas para busca de historico
ForEach ($i in -7..0) 
{
    $d = Get-Date 
    $DtConsulta[$i] = $d.AddDays($i)
    $DtDropDown.Items.Add( $DtConsulta[$i].ToLongDateString()) | Out-Null
}
```

How can I filter by startfine?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ProcessName` and not `StartTime` in your `Where-Object` statement. `($_.ProcessName -like "$Dtchoice" )`

Also, you're trying to compare a string representing a date with a `DateTime`-object.

```
PS > $t.StartTime
torsdag 14. januar 2016 17.30.57

PS > $dtchoice
torsdag 14. januar 2016
```

You need to convert the `StartTime` datetime to a similar format like this:

```
PS > $t.StartTime.ToLongDateString()
torsdag 14. januar 2016

PS > $dtchoice
torsdag 14. januar 2016
```

I would suggest a `where`-test like `($_.StartTime -and ($_.StartTime.ToLongDateString() -eq "$dtchoice"))` . Ex.

```
$gps = Get-Process |
Where-Object {($_.ProcessName -like "$choice" ) -and ($_.StartTime -and ($_.StartTime.ToLongDateString() -eq "$dtchoice")) } |
Select-Object id,name,cpu,starttime |
Sort-Object -Descending starttime
```

I included a `$_.StartTime` check there too to skip processes that you can't read the `StartTime`-property from like the `Idle`-process.